# Integration testing a library that supports streaming gzipped http responses

Tags: streaming, gzip, integration-testing

I want to write an integration test for a library that handles streamed http responses that are chunked and gzipped.

Are there any services or other suggestions I could use to do this?

Ideal endpoint or service would have:

- Free
- Chunked
- No authentication needed
- Sending at least 5k of gzipped content

The [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) would be perfect if it didn't require an account.

Maybe I'm over-thinking this, please say so and I'll eat my humble pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like github.com returns chunked gzip.  Example:

```
curl --compressed -v https://github.com/madler/zlib/commits/develop > /dev/null
...
< Server: nginx/1.0.13
< Date: Sun, 01 Apr 2012 21:32:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 200 OK
< ETag: "bae161c1cbcaa8882f8b5c6cb1d1d270"
< X-Frame-Options: deny
< X-Runtime: 107
< Set-Cookie: _gh_sess=BAh7BzoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlZjhkOWYxYzUzMzhjMTIxZTRmYjUyZTY2MWY0YWVjZGI6EF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjFUK2dFR1podXlTMjcralpLUmkyTkpYZzE5ZzBLS3BLODl0OTE0VEt0ZGdJPQ%3D%3D--95e44cf6b548b93a682fdefcbca6b84cb034ca8b; path=/; expires=Sat, 01-Jan-2022 00:00:00 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
< Content-Encoding: gzip
<
```

Comment: Yep, I was over-thinking it. Thanks much.